# how to create rabl view for two objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rabl

i need to create rabl view for two objects

```
def communities
@communities = Community.all
@religions = Religion.all
end
```

I have tried with following

```
object @communities
attribute :id, :name
object @religions
attribute :id, :name
```

but it shows only second object..

how do i create view for both object?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **child** property if there are any associations between communities and religion.

```
child @communities object_root: false do
   attributes :id, :name
end
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, there is no association between them